# can't upload image to cloudinary from firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, cloudinary

According to cloudinary's [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#private_storage_url) one should be able to upload an image to cloudinary using google cloud storage.

However when I attempt to do so, I get the following error in my cloud functions logs.

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'gs://my-bucket.appspot.com/01.jpg'
```

this is my cloud function:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as cloudinary from 'cloudinary';

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: functions.config().cloudinary.cloudname,
  api_key: functions.config().cloudinary.apikey,
  api_secret: functions.config().cloudinary.apisecret,
});


export const uploadImageToCloudinary = functions.storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize(object => {
    cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(
      `gs://${object.bucket}/${object.name}`,
      function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error)
          return;
        }
        console.log(result);
      }
    );
  })
```

I have added `/.wellknown/cloudinary/<cloudinary_cloudname>` to my bucket as well added permission in cloud platform to allow cloudinary `object viewer` access

Is there an extra step I'm missing - I can't seem to get this working?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudinary does support Google cloud storage upload, but it's a relatively new feature and the current version of the node SDK doesn't handle `gs://` urls.

In your example, it's trying to resolve the `gs://` URL on the local server and send the image to Cloudinary, rather than sending the URL to Cloudinary so the fetch happens from Cloudinary's side.

Until this is added to the SDK, you could get this working by triggering the fetch [using the URL-based upload method](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/fetch_remote_images), or by making a small change to the SDK code.

Specifically, it's a small change in [`lib/uploader.js`](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/blob/2c35586976bf879b69cb3ff8990692ae693aedaa/lib/uploader.js#L68) - you need to add the `gs:` prefix there, after which it should work OK.

Diff:

```
diff --git a/lib/uploader.js b/lib/uploader.js
index 2f71eaa..af08e14 100644
--- a/lib/uploader.js
+++ b/lib/uploader.js
@@ -65,7 +65,7 @@
     return call_api("upload", callback, options, function() {
       var params;
       params = build_upload_params(options);
-      if ((file != null) && file.match(/^ftp:|^https?:|^s3:|^data:[^;]*;base64,([a-zA-Z0-9\/+\n=]+)$/)) {
+      if ((file != null) && file.match(/^ftp:|^https?:|^gs:|^s3:|^data:[^;]*;base64,([a-zA-Z0-9\/+\n=]+)$/)) {
         return [
           params, {
             file: file
```

After applying that diff, I did successfully fetch an image from Google Cloud Storage

Comment: Perfect! this worked like a charm. I had to fork it to use in loud functions, but I'm just happy to get it working!